# Compute product of all combinations of a dataframe column with two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, numpy

I have pandas dataframe consisting of 3 columns that has information regarding loans:

```
LoanKey  ProbOfDefault    EL(expected loss)
1          100%             546
2          90%              102
3.         92%              1009
.           .                .
.           .                .
.           .                .
303        13%              68
```

I need to find a combination of loans with the highest cumulative `EL` value that will have a probability of default between `0.9%-1%.`

For example, a single combination can consist of 3 loans:

```
loan1 - PD=30%; EL=372
loan2 - PD=10%; EL=1792
loan3 - PD=3%;  EL=123

cummulative EL=372+1792+123=2287
cummulative PD = 30%*10%*3%=0.9%
```

I tried converting my pandas columns to lists and using `itertools.combinations` to find all possible combinations of loans and calculating PD and EL of each combination, picking one with `0.9%<=PD<=1%` and max. EL, but my solution took too long to compute since a number of possible combinations is extremely large.

Is there a smarter way of solving this problem?

Comment: Don't know how large your data set is or how close to optimal you want to be, but a greedy heuristic approach of sorting by PD and taking all the loans until you'd pass 1% cumulative would likely yield a reasonably good outcome.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Randy. My dataset consists of 310 observations so it's not too large. Do you have an example of what a greedy heuristic algorithm could look like? Or how would I go about sorting by PD? Would it be by descending order?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, here's an example.

First, I'm creating a random dataframe and sorting by the PD column:

```
In [178]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random([20000, 2]), columns=['pd', 'lgd'])
In [179]: df.sort_values("pd", inplace=True)
```

Then you can calculate cumulative values for the two columns:

```
In [180]: df['cumul_pd'] = df['pd'].expanding().mean()
In [181]: df['cumul_lgd'] = df['lgd'].cumsum()
```

From there, you can pick off the last value where `cumul_pd < 0.1`:

```
In [182]: df[df['cumul_pd'] <= 0.01].tail(1)[['cumul_pd', 'cumul_lgd']]
Out[182]:
       cumul_pd   cumul_lgd
16553  0.009997  203.962193
```

As I mentioned, there's no guarantee this is an optimal solution, but it should likely be close assuming there aren't gigantic swings in the loss column.